# What to storage to use?

Tags: storage

could you please help me with choosing the affordable HP storage?

Requirements are:

1) ethernet for data connection
2) RAID 0/1
3) minimum 12 HDD SATA

Virtual machines have to be stored there, through NFS.

Comment: What do you mean by affordable - a general ballpark budget would be useful (<$5k, $10K, $100K). Affordable means very different things to different people.  By "Ethernet for Data connection" do you mean iSCSI, NFS, CIFS, AOE, FCOE or something else? How many VM? Are you worried about resilience (you should be IMO but its your call)? RAID 0 - would you seriously use RAID 0 to host production VM's?

Answer (score 2):

Larger server. Sorry. 12 HDD rule out every NAS device (with iscsi) that i know, pretty much all max out at 8 discs.

- Get an ISCSI SAN smoewhere. Dell, HP have them.
- Or get a storage server. I know SuperMicro has cases with up to 72 discs in one case. Small motherboard, OS etc., finished.

At the end of the day, 12hdd is too alrge for a smaller / cheaper SAN/NAS combo.

For more detailed answer, you did not care enough to provide enough requirements to make more than totally wild guesses. Your question is akin to asking "whati s the best car, needs to have minimum 4 tires and run on fuel". No clue what the makes a car the best for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to consider:

- How fast do you want it to be?
- How much data do you want to store?
- How do you want to aceess you data (you already said nfs, but dunno why)
- How much money you have for this?
- What kind of data security (disk fail tolerance) is required? (raid0 and raid1 are the opposite to each other)